# How to highlight the outline of an subdivision where mouse is hovering?

Tags: openlayers-3

For example,highlight the city's outline where mouse is hovering.I have read this:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35395/how-to-highlight-a-selected-country

I have got some questions:

1. By openlayers,I can't get the outline latlangs of mouse hovering subdivision(a state or a city) directly,am I right?
2. To get it done,I must get the point info(latlng or others) of mouse hovering, then query out the latlangs by this point info，am I right?
3. If it is,any public api can be queried? Or I must build a database for this kind of query by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your questions,

1 - you will need the states or cities defined in a file like GeoJSON, but if you have that, then yes, you can get the outline as a feature.

2 - Yes - you can do this using map.on('pointermove' ...) or adding a condition to the select interaction for pointermove.

3 - I think this is related to (1) - broadly speaking you can use anything that returns a suitable format such as GeoJSON.

This example shows GeoJSON being used with clicks to select country boundaries:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/box-selection.html

Reworking that with pointermove should give you what you need. The easiest way is this:

```
var highlighter = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});
```

I've done this as a demo for you:

http://www.freytag.org.uk/ol/hover.html